# Правда ли?

Tags: фразеология

Попалось вот такое продолжение пословицы. Честно говоря, никогда не слышал о таком окончании, поэтому спрашивают у знатоков: действительно она полностью звучит так, или это розыгрыш?
Спасибо.

[image]

Comment: Словами  напишите - фотография  не  открывается  полностью.

Comment: Фото открылось.  Думаю,  что  это  новодел.  Попытка  наделить  пословицу  новым  смыслом.  Но  не  розыгрыш.

Answer (score 2):

Разумеется, первоначально народная пословица была без продолжения.

Смысл был: "не торопись, не суетись, делай всё с расстановкой -- быстрее достигнешь цели"
Этакая крестьянская степенность...

Продолжение возникло, насколько я могу судить, где-то в начале 1960-х.
Тоже в народе.

Жизнь убыстрялась, и старые формулы иногда давали сбой.
Сыграла роль и политическая оттепель: народ раскрепостился, стал критичнее и свободнее относиться к прошлому.

Остроумное добавление переиначило поговорку, привело её к новым условиям.
Используется как опровержение, как возражение на старую мудрость.
Новый смысл: "Тщательные приготовления не позволят сделать работу к сроку".

Пользуйтесь обоими вариантами в зависимости от обстановки -)

Comment: Мне  это  напоминает  армейский  вариант  переиначивания  пословицы  "кто не  работает,  тот  не  ест" -  кто  не  работает,  тот  ест.